# workflow 2013 error

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a sharepoint 2013 farm with 4 servers. I install and configure workflow manager 1.0 successfully. when I create a workflow of template workflow 2010 on my list it create and run properly.

First time I create a workflow of template workflow 2013 on my lists, It create successfully but when I run it, nothing happens I got error “there is some problem, reload the page and try again.” and state of workflow change to idle,  but now when I try to create another workflow of template workflow 2013 on my lists, I get the following error:

Server-side activities have been updated. You need to restart SharePoint Designer to use the updated version of activities.

I try to restart SharePoint Designer but the problem exists. I try to delete cache, uninstall the SharePoint Designer and install it again but nothing changed

Any solution?

Comment: Permission to the user ...on what ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission via an AD Group the workflow 2013 not work, you need give permission directly to user.